# Printing a set of numbers within a range whose individual digits are all divisible by 3

Tags: java, conditional-statements

How to create a Java program to check and print all the numbers in a range(say 100-150) whose individual digits are all divisible by 3? I keep trying but end up causing an infinite loop

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since 1 isn't divisible by 3, there is no such number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for (int i = 100; i <= 150; i++) {
        if (i%3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since 99 is obviously divisible by 3, 102 should be the first number, from there you can go with i+=3; the only problem is, that these numbers are divisible by 3, while the question asks for all digits being divisible by 3.